# Creating a pandas dataframe in a while loop with exception handling not reading the dataframe after

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first post here. So I had python script to do some algorithmic trading. It worked fine on coinbase but when I tried switching some of the code to work with binance it's not working. Below is the error I get. I made sure I copy and paste the df name to make sure it's the same name. I'm not sure why the print statement is unable to print the df. I will also paste the part of the code that isn't working to see if someone can make it work. In my actual code instead of print is where I start calculating the Moving Averages but I get the same error with just print so some for some reason the dataframe isn't being created. Any help will be appreciated.

*Error Encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 44, in 
print(historic_df)
NameError: name 'historic_df' is not defined*

The code:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import pandas as pd

currency = 'BTCUSD'

base = 'https://api.binance.com'
endpoint = '/api/v1/klines'
params = '?&symbol='+currency+'&interval=1h'
url = base + endpoint + params

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Begin Loop and get Historic Data ###

    while True:
    
         try:
             #Pulls the historical data from binance. The interval is defined in params variable
             data = requests.get(url)
             dictionary = json.loads(data.text)
    
             # The line below just puts the historic data we pulled into a data frame
             historic_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
             historic_df = historic_df.drop(range(6,12), axis=1)
    
             # This gives the columns meaning full names based on what we pull
             historic_df.columns = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volumne']
    
             # Changing the columns to floats
             historic_df['open'] = historic_df['open'].astype(float)
             historic_df['high'] = historic_df['high'].astype(float)
             historic_df['low'] = historic_df['low'].astype(float)
             historic_df['close'] = historic_df['close'].astype(float)
             historic_df['volume'] = historic_df['volume'].astype(float)
    
             # Get latest data and show to the user for reference
             btc_price = bi_client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=currency)
             currentPrice = float(btc_price['price'])
    
         except:`enter code here`
             print("Error Encountered")
    
         print(historic_df)
```

Comment: Well, the obvious reason for the error is the use of `try-except`. Some exception happens in the `try` block and it exits without executing and as a result, `historic_df` variable is never defined.

Comment: You are setting yourself for so much headache by using plain `except`. You have to catch **specific** errors and if you're catching all of them you should at least print the error stack.

Comment: But if the exception happens and it exits without building the dataframe shouldn't it have the output of "Error Encountered" that I have in the exception? Instead of moving on to the print statement below saying it's not defined, or maybe print the error encountered and break on the print historic_df line?

Comment: `Error Encountered Traceback (most recent call last): File "test2.py", line 44, in print(historic_df) NameError: name 'historic_df' is not defined` - that's your error, right? Do you see *Error Encountered* anywhere?

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much... Can't believe I missed that...

Comment: No problem. I would suggest to read up on Exception handling. This is really not a good way of dealing with exceptions and will eventually lead to some difficult-to-debug code.

Comment: Yes thanks, the other post from @ndclt provided a link so I will definitely read through that tonight. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter comes from how you manage your errors. It come from the line `json.loads(data.text)`. `data` does not contains correct json. As you except every Exception, you print "Error Encountered" and your code does not create the variable `historic_df` as it fails before.

You should write something more like this:

```py
import requests
import json
import time
import pandas as pd
from requests import HTTPError

currency = 'BTCUSD'

base = 'https://api.binance.com'
endpoint = '/api/v1/klines'
params = '?&symbol=' + currency + '&interval=1h'
url = base + endpoint + params

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Begin Loop and get Historic Data ###

while True:
    try:
        # Pulls the historical data from binance. The interval is defined in params variable
        data = requests.get(url)
        data.raise_for_status()

        dictionary = data.json()

        # The line below just puts the historic data we pulled into a data frame
        historic_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
        historic_df = historic_df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)
        # I delete other code
    except HTTPError as err:
        print(err)
    except as err:
        print(err)
```

You should read for a more detailed the [tutorial about exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).